# typescript suddenly ignores d.ts files

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a typescript vue project and I have extended the vue definitions to add some additional properties:

I have multiple xxx.d.ts files with content like this:

vue-analytics.d.ts:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $ga: any
    }
}
```

vue-router.d.ts:

```
import VueRouter, {Route} from "vue-router"

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
    interface Vue {
        $router: VueRouter
        $route: Route
    }
}
```

This worked great until today.

Now typescript complains:

```
Property '$ga' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
```

Even though I did not change anything and the d.ts files are still in the same place and unchanged.

It works fine when I add the definitions directly to the file in the node_modules folder (vue/types/vue.d.ts)